# Update helper file with Redux store

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I have a Colors.js file which contains some vars such as:

```
const textColor = 'white';
const primaryColor = 'blue';
```

I then import this file in a components styling and use it as such:

```
import Colors from './Colors';
const styles = {
    component: { color: Colors.textColor }
}
```

Now I would like to connect this Colors.js file to my redux store; so I can theme my app. For example, wrapping my Colors.js file in a connect function, however, this doesn't work as the Colors.js is called way before the store is initialized.

I also tried getState() and importing the store manually, but I did not receive any props.

Is there a different approach I could take?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the colors.js into a reducer and set it as such. In the reducer, set your initialState to default colors you need, and also export that initialState object, so you can import it in other files. Now you can import that initialState and use it anywhere you want in the app, which will be constant, and also you will have that same colors object in redux store, which you can connect to any component you have and use and manipulate it too, with redux actions.

Comment: Hi, I thought about this method but I would need to get the redux state in my components styles.js file. When I do so, it is called before the redux store is setup and thus all the props are undefined. My main trouble has been finding a workaround for this. Thank you for any help!

Comment: For this, you can try using `redux-persist`. It is an NPM package that lets you store your redux data even after you close/exit the app, and while you reopen, it automatically puts the persisted data in redux store instead of the hard coded initialState. You can save the colors stuff in a separate reducer and chose to persist only that particular reducer. And make use of `persist-gateway` to delay app rendering until `redux-persist` load your data intro store, thus making sure it is not undefined at the time of rendering. I hope you find this answer helpful. Good luck.